# Advance custom fields variable with if statement & Function

Tags: php, functions, advanced-custom-fields

I'm new in php & WordPress in general but I searched all the stackexchange website to find the proper advice with no luck so I hope I ask in proper way.

I have simple PHP function with if statement look like this:

```
function wp_admin_restrection(){
            if( !current_user_can('administrator') && $wpAdminRestrection ){

              do something
            }
         }
```

Where `$wpAdminRestrection = get_field('disable_wp_admin_for_non_admin', 'option');`

My problem is, the above function not working as its written but if I write like this:

```
function wp_admin_restrection(){
                if( !current_user_can('administrator') && get_field('disable_wp_admin_for_non_admin ){

                  do something
                }
             }
```

it will work with no issue.

According to ACF documentation , I should use get_field for this situation and not the_field.

Would you please advise me?

**NOTE**
This seem to only happen with True/False field as its working fine with other fields so far.

Comment: In your first function, I don't see where you defined `$wpAdminRestrection`. And please format your code, it has a syntax error in the second function (unclosed `'`).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. And I already formatted the code. The $wpAdminRestrection I called locally inside the function as all my other codes. I also edit the note in my question as this look like happening only with True/False field.

Comment: Where are calling `wp_admin_restrection()`? Functions.php?

Comment: Thank you again, its in my own plugin and everything works fine but not this, sorry for delay